# Best way to tell if a comment is from a user?

Tags: comments, users, functions, avatar

I've got an `if ($comment->user_id)` block to pick an default admin comment gravatar (different than a non-user's). But I'd still like this gravatar to be used if a user comments using their registered email, even if they comment while not logged in. What is the best way to test for this?

**EDIT**

I'm already using

```
 if ($comment->user_id){
            //comment by registered user
            $avatar = '/images/bird_comments_big.png';
            }else{
            //comment by none registered user
            $avatar = '/images/bird_comments_pink.png';
            }
```

with

```
<div><?php echo get_avatar($comment, 70, get_bloginfo('template_url').$avatar); ?></div>
```

If the user is logged in a makes a comments, the if statement is indeed fulfilled. However, if the user uses their registered email (i.e. tied to their login in WP) without bring logged in, `user_id` is not present, and the icon for the unregistered user appears. **`user_id` is only stored if the user is logged in.**

*I also want to test if the email given matches a registered user, regardless if they are logged-in or not.*

Comment: You can use get_ avatar http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar

Comment: @Bainternet Yes, I do eventually use this function, but I'm trying to have a default user avatar that is different than the default commenter avatar. So I need a way to determine which default to pass to `get_avatar()`.

Comment: get_avatar() accepts email so you can pass the comment email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($comment->user_id || email_exists($comment->comment_author_email)){
            //comment by registered user
            $avatar = '/images/registered_user.png';
            }else{
            //comment by none registered user
            $avatar = '/images/non_registered_user.png';
            }
```

with

```
<div><?php echo get_avatar($comment, 70, get_bloginfo('template_url').$avatar); ?></div>
```

Seems about as succinct a way I can figure.

Comment: I guess, the `$comment->user_id` is a string. ('0' / '1'), So the way you're using it in `if` statement is wrong.

Comment: It does what I want it to do. You find this semantically wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You can simplly check

```
if ($comment->user_id > 0){
//comment by registered user
}else{
//comment by none registered user
}
```

Comment: I don't think you're understanding.... I already posited this part in my question. I'm going to try and rephrase...

Comment: @two7s_clash When a non user comments, his `$comment->user_id` values is set to `0` So @Bainternet provided simple way to distinguish registered user's comments.

Comment: I totally get that and I was already doing a version on that in my example.